# Linq query, build nested objects with single datatable

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, linq, nested

I have a very large datatable, here is a snapshot of it:

```
Section         |SectionId |    Lesson                | LessonId  | Activity           |    Date    |     Time   | Score |  Duration
                |          |                          |           |                    |            |            |       |             
Functions       |   123    | Intro to Functions       | 6374      |  Activity Quiz 1   |  6/10/2014 |  18:55:00  |  80   |   5
Functions       |   123    | Intro to Functions       | 6374      |  Domain and Range  |  6/10/2014 |  19:33:00  |  0    |   36
Functions       |   123    | Intro to Functions       | 6374      |  Activity Quiz 2   |  6/10/2014 |  19:37:00  |  100  |   4
Linear Functions|   124    | Intro to Linear Functions| 6378      |  Authentic Task: 1 |  6/23/2014 |  13:54:00  |  0    |   0
Linear Functions|   124    | Intro to Linear Functions| 6378      |  Activity Quiz: 3  |  6/18/2014 |  14:12:00  |  80   |   4
Linear Functions|   124    | Intro to Linear Functions| 6378      |  Step Functions    |  6/18/2014 |  14:59:00  |  0    |   46
```

I have the follow c# classes:

```
    public class Section
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lesson
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Activity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public int LessonId { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to build nested JSON that can be consumed by Angular, something like this:

```
[{ Name: "Functions", 
   Lessons: [{ Name: "Intro to Functions",
           Activities: [ 
                 { Name: "Activity Quiz 1", Duration: 5, Date: "6/10/2014", Time: "18:55:00", Score: 80}, 
                 {Name: "Domain and Range", Duration: 36, Date: "6/10/2014", Time: "19:33:00", Score: 0}, 
                 {Name: "Activity Quiz 2", Duration: 4, Date: "6/10/2014", Time: "19:37:00", Score: 100}
                           ]
          }]
 }, 
{ Name: "Linear Functions", 
   Lessons: [{ Name: "Intro To Linear Functions",
           Activities: [ 
                 {Name: "Authentic Task: 1", Duration: 0, CompletedDate: "6/23/2014", CompletedTime: "13:54:00", Score: 0}, 
                 {Name: "Activity Quiz 3", Duration: 4, CompletedDate: "6/18/2014", CompletedTime: "14:12:00", Score: 80}, 
                 {Name: "Step Functions", Duration: 46, CompletedDate: "6/18/2014", CompletedTime: "14:59:00", Score: 0}
                           ]
          }]
 }
]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
    var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => new { ID = r["Section"] })
        .Select(c => new Section
        {
            Name = c.Key.ID.ToString(),
            Lessons = c.Select(l => new Lesson
                {
                    Name = l["Lesson"].ToString(),
                    Activities = c.
                    .Select(a => new Activity
                    {
                        Name = a["Activity"].ToString(),
                        CompletedDate = a["Date"].ToString(),
                        CompletedTime = a["Time"].ToString(),
                        Score = Convert.ToInt32(a["Score"]),
                        Duration = Convert.ToInt32(a["Duration"])
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Unfortunately, it does not return the correct data. The sections seem to come back fine, but the activities are not correctly linked to the Lessons, instead they are linked to the sections. So I tried leveraging the Ids and breaking it down into pieces:

```
var data = dt.AsEnumerable();

var sections = data
    .GroupBy(r => new { ID = r["SectionId"] }).Select(c => new Chapter
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(c.Key.ID),
        Name = c.Select(n => n["Section"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
    }).Distinct().ToList();

var lessons = data
    .GroupBy(r => new { ID = r["LessonId"] }).Select(c => new Lesson
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(c.Key.ID),
        Name = c.Select(n => n["Lesson"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
    }).Distinct().ToList();

var activities = data
    .Select(l => new Activity
    {
        Name = l["Activity"].ToString(),
        LessonId = Convert.ToInt32(l["LessonId"])
    }).ToList();
```

The data for each individual query looks right, but ultimately I am still not able to get the data as I want it. Any help or suggestions are appreciated

EDIT:

Here is the Angular data binding portion (studentData is the nested object on scope):

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Activities</th>
                        <th>Completed Date</th>
                        <th>Completed Time</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Duration (hh:mm:ss)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="section in studentData">
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>{{section.Name}}</strong></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr ng-repeat="lesson in section.Lessons">
                    <td>
                     <table>
                        <tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{lesson.Name}}</td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="activity in lesson.Activities">
                          <td>{{activity.Name}}</td>
                          <td>{{activity.CompletedDate}}</td>
                          <td>{{activity.CompletedTime}}</td>
                          <td>{{activity.Score}}</td>
                          <td>{{activity.Score}}</td>
                          <td>{{activity.Duration}}</td>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was over complicating things:

```
 var data = dt.AsEnumerable();

    var sections = data
        .GroupBy(r => new { ID = r["SectionId"] }).Select(c => new Chapter
        {
            Id = (int)c.Select(n => n["SectionId"]).FirstOrDefault(),
            Name = (string)c.Select(n => n["Section"]).FirstOrDefault(),
            Lessons = new List<Lesson>()
        }).Distinct().ToList();

    var lessons = data
        .GroupBy(r => new { ID = r["LessonId"] }).Select(l => new Lesson
        {
            Id = (int)l.Select(n => n["LessonId"]).FirstOrDefault(),
            Name = l.Select(n => n["Lesson"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
            Activities = new List<Activity>(),
            ChapterId = (int)l.Select(n => n["SectionId"]).FirstOrDefault()
        }).Distinct().ToList();

    var activities = data
        .Select(a => new Activity
        {
            Name = (string)a["Activity"],
            Date = (string)a["Date"],
            Time = (string)a["Time"],
            Score = (int)a["Score"],
            Duration = (int)a["Duration"],
            LessonId = (int)a["Lessonid"]
        }).ToList();


    foreach (var lesson in lessons)
    {
        var activitiesToAdd = activities.Where(a => a.LessonId == lesson.Id);
        lesson.Activities.AddRange(activitiesToAdd);
    }

    foreach (var section in sections)
    {
        var lessonsToAdd = lessons.Where(l => l.SectionId == section.Id);
        section.Lessons.AddRange(lessonsToAdd);
    }
```

sections now contains the nested object

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
var grps= 
    dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
        .GroupBy (r => r["SectionId"].ToString() + "|" + r["Section"].ToString() 
                      + "|" + r["LessonId"].ToString() + "|" + r["Lesson"].ToString()
                      + "|" + r["Activity"].ToString() + "|" + r["Date"].ToString()  + "|" + r["Time"].ToString() 
                 );
```